# Copy/Past format with conditionnals rules

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in a sheet.

I clear all contents of the table in a macro.

But I want a special format in each Column :

A : Center, Bold, Standard format…
B : Left, Number format…

The question is How can I fit Columns to my desired format without forget the conditionnals rules !

Because actually my code is like this :

```
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B2").Select ''''' mise en forme Standar
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Not really efficient… I copy B2 to paste to the rest of column B...

Comment: I'd suggest using a cell style rather than relying on copy/pasting one particular cell's formatting.  You could then name that style and apply that to any cells that require it.

Comment: there are too manies différences from each rows

Comment: Let's assume you have 26 columns in your table and that you're applying the formatting from the top row to everything in that column - are you saying that you have a different style for each column?

Comment: Yes, I have number, percent, standard format with center, right, left text, with different colors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you want to apply the formatting from the top row to the rest of the cells in that column without losing the conditional formatting of those destination cells.

You can achieve this with a slight modification to your existing code, so instead of:

```
Range("B2").Copy
```

make it this, so all of the formats from the top row are picked up in one go:

```
Range("B2:G2").Copy
```

Then you can then apply the formats to the whole region in one step:

```
Selection.CurrentRegion.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

This will apply the formatting from the top row to each of the rows below, maintaining the formatting for each column and, crucially, the conditional formatting.